# Get New Insert News in JSON API

Tags: android, json, notifications

I created a News application. It successfully retrieves the news from news API URL I mention in code. However, I want to have a notification in every device that will notify the user if there's a piece of new news. I try to not use GSM and FCM. Is there a possibility I can create a notification without GCM and FCM. Just using asyntask only? Thank you for the response.

FRAGMENT ACTIVITY   https://pastecode.xyz/view/591c3d14

NEWS ADAPTER https://pastecode.xyz/view/b4457c2a

I tried to use

```
  class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        sPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
        checker = sPref.getString(savedText, "0");

        if(datanews != checker){
            downloadNews = new DownloadNews();
            DownloadNews.showNotification = true;
            downloadNews.execute();
        } else {
            downloadNews = new DownloadNews();
            DownloadNews.showNotification = true;
            downloadNews.execute();
        }
    }
```

and

```
` if(showNotification)createNotification(getActivity()); `
```

inside the asyntask post execute but not displaying the notification it gives me error.  for this situation